# linux uptime history

Tags: linux

How can I get a history of uptimes for my debian box? After a reboot, I dont see an option for the uptime command to print a history of uptimes. If it matters, I would like to use these uptimes for graphing a page in php to show my webservers uptime lengths between boots.

Update: 
Not sure if it is based on a length of time or if last gets reset on reboot but I only get the most recent boot timestamp with the last command. last -x also does not return any further info.  Sounds like a script is my best bet.

Update:
Uptimed is the information I am looking for, not sure how to grep that info in code. Managing my own script for a db sounds like the best fit for an application.

Comment: You could record the uptime in a db or file every 5 minutes and print it in your graph so if the server restarts you could see the uptime in graph as a peak

Comment: +1 but...  Who needs history of uptime on Debian systems?  Here's the uptime on one of my Debian box: *# uptime 
 23:51:06 up 1067 days*    : )  (yup, that one server will soon reach 3 years of uptime... Gosh, I love the stability of Debian :)   And interestingly enough, I realize that during these 3 years the clock did drift quite a bit (gonna fix this right away)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could create a simple script which runs uptime and dumps it to a file.

```
uptime >> uptime.log
```

Then set up a cron job for it.

Answer (score 52):

Install [uptimed](https://github.com/rpodgorny/uptimed). It does exactly what you want.

Edit:

You can apparantly include it in a PHP page as easily as this:

```
<? system("/usr/local/bin/uprecords -a -B"); ?>
```

[Examples](https://web.archive.org/web/20090228064718/http://www.robertjohnkaper.com/software/uptimed/example.html)

Comment: this is the best and true answer to this question.

Comment: Second link is broken.

Comment: Well to be fair it was 7 years ago I answered this question. I've got no way to track down the examples now unfortunately

Comment: just run `uprecords --help` for help. It is not always in `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 34):

the [`last`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_last.htm) command will give you the reboot times of the system. You could take the difference between each successive reboot and that should give the uptime of the machine.

**update**

[1800 INFORMATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79490/linux-uptime-history#79553) answer is a better solution.

Comment: This however doesn't take into account shutdowns. The pseudo user reboot only appears in last when the system reboot.

Comment: Would that include account reboots as well?

Comment: for me is does take shutdowns into account and seems to be the best solution:)

Answer (score 19):

Try this out:

```
last | grep reboot
```

Comment: that's great, could you explain a bit more how to get uptime from last command?

Comment: you can just run `last reboot`

Answer (score 16):

according to `last` manual page:

> The pseudo user reboot logs in each time the system  is  rebooted.
>          Thus last reboot will show a log of all reboots since the log file
>          was created.

so last column of `#last reboot` command gives you uptime history:

```
#last reboot
reboot   system boot  **************** Sat Sep 21 03:31 - 08:27 (1+04:56)   
reboot   system boot  **************** Wed Aug  7 07:08 - 08:27 (46+01:19)
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't stored between boots, but [The Uptimes Project](http://www.uptimes-project.org) is a third-party option to track it, with software for a range of platforms.

Another tool available on Debian is [uptimed](http://podgorny.cz/moin/Uptimed) which tracks uptimes between boots.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a cron job to run at the required resolution (say 10 minutes) by entering the following [on *one* single line - I've just separated it for formatting purposes] in your crontab (cron -l to list, cron -e to edit).

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * *
    /bin/echo $(/bin/date +\%Y-\%m-\%d) $(/usr/bin/uptime)
    >>/tmp/uptime.hist 2>&1
```

This appends the date, time and uptime to the uptime.hist file every ten minutes while the machine is running. You can then examine this file manually to figure out the information or write a script to process it as you see fit.

Whenever the uptime reduces, there's been a reboot since the previous record. When there are large gaps between lines (i.e., more than the expected ten minutes), the machine's been down during that time.

Comment: need to escacpe the percent signs with backslash or cron will interpret them

Answer (score 1):

i dont think this information is saved between reboots.

if shutting down properly you could run a command on shutdown that saves the uptime, that way you could read it back after booting back up.

Answer (score 1):

This information is not normally saved. However, you can sign up for an online service that will do this for you. You just install a client that will send your uptime to the server every 5 minutes and the site will present you with a graph of your uptimes:

http://uptimes-project.org/

Comment: Why would I send my data to some server to do that when I can simply store it on my own machine?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use tuptime https://sourceforge.net/projects/tuptime/ for a total uptime time.

Comment: i don't know tuptime yet, but it's a great discover. Works very well

Answer (score 1):

You can use tuptime, a simple command for report the total uptime in linux keeping it betwwen reboots.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tuptime/

Answer (score 1):

Since I haven't found an answer here that would help retroactively, maybe this will help someone.

kern.log (depending on your distribution) should log a timestamp.
It will be something like:
2019-01-28T06:25:25.459477+00:00 someserver kernel: [44114473.614361] somemessage

"44114473.614361" represents seconds since last boot, from that you can calculate the uptime without having to install anything.

Answer (score 1):

## Use Syslog

For anyone coming here searching for their past uptime.
The solution of @1800_Information is a good advise for the future, but I needed to find information for my past uptimes on a specific date.

Therefore I used syslog to determine when that day the system was started (first log entry of that day) and when the system was shutdown again.

### Boot time

To get the system start time grep for the month and day and show only the first lines:

```
sudo grep "May 28" /var/log/syslog* | head
```

### Shutdown time

To get the system shutdown time grep for the month and day and show only the last few lines:

```
sudo grep "May 28" /var/log/syslog* | tail
```

Answer (score 0):

Nagios can make even very beautiful diagrams about this.